# Unique baseball scoring situation: Who gets the Win?

Tags: baseball, mlb, scoring

The question is which pitcher gets the win A or B?

My baseball team played a double header (each game 7 innings) recently. Pitcher A started game 2. Because he also pitched in game one (all 7 innings), he only went 3 innings in game 2. He didn't give up a run and when he left the game his team was winning 4-0.

Pitcher B came in to pitch the 4th, 5th 6th and 7th innings and never gave up the lead. However he did give up 4 runs in four innings. The final score of the game was 11-4.

Under MLB rules, who is credited with the win? A or B? And why?

Answer (score 6):

According to the [official MLB rules](http://mlb.mlb.com/mlb/official_info/official_rules/official_scorer_10.jsp), I believe pitcher B would be credited with the win in the second game because of the fact that the starting pitcher only went 3 innings in that game.

See rule 10.17(b):

> (b) If the pitcher whose team assumes a lead while such pitcher is in
>   the game, or during the inning on offense in which such pitcher is
>   removed from the game, and does not relinquish such lead, is a
>   starting pitcher who has not completed (1) five innings of a game that
>   lasts six or more innings on defense, or (2) four innings of a game
>   that lasts five innings on defense, then the official scorer shall
>   credit as the winning pitcher the relief pitcher, if there is only one
>   relief pitcher, or the relief pitcher who, in the official scorers
>   judgment was the most effective, if there is more than one relief
>   pitcher.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing too unique about this - Pitcher A didn't pitch 5 innings so he can't get the win.